# Custom multi select filter issue for the customer grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I've made a custom multiselect customer attribute. The attribute code is: `email_preference`.
I've added this code to get a multiselect filter in the `app/code/Vendor/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="email_preference">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">\Vendor\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\EmailPreference</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email preferences</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

In the `\Vendor\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\EmailPreference` I have:

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

```
class EmailPreference extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions(): array
    {
        $this->_options = [];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Value1', 'value' => 'value1'];
        $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Value2, 'value' => 'value2'];

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

This filter works only if I have one value assigned to a customer. If I have multi values assinged, it will render in the grid like this: `Value1,Value2`, however If I select Value1 and Value2 from the filter , I will only get customers with one values assigned. Either `Value1` or `Value2` , but not `Value1,Value`.
For example, in this case, if I select Value1 and Value2 from the multiselect:

```
Customer 1 -> Value1
Customer 2 -> Value2
Customer 3 -> Value1,Value2
```

I will get only Customer 1 and Customer 2, not Customer 3. How can I change my filter to make this work ? or What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try making your column multiselect instead of select `<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>`. Not sure if it works, but it's easy to test

Comment: thanks for suggestion @Marius, but it does not work . I followed this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186608/6204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got something.
Here is what happens (I think).

When you apply a filter on the customer `email_preference` field this is actually applied to the collection query.
(Let's imagine that the customer entity is flat even if it's EAV. it's easier to explain.)

```
WHERE email_preference IN ('value1', 'value2');`
```

but since in your database you have saved like a string `value1,value2` this is never going to get matched.

What may possible work is to make the filter look like this

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value1', email_preference) AND FIND_IN_SET ('value2', 'email_preference')
```

This is a part of the stack trace where you may be able to hook to do this.

- `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider::getSearchResult`
- `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting::search`
- `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool::applyFilters`
- **`Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider::apply`**
- `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection::addFieldToFilter`

I would go with an `aroundPlugin` (I know, ugly, but I have no better idea for now) on `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider::apply`

where you can do something like this

```
public function aroundApply(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter $subject,
     callable $proceed;
     \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection,
     \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter
)
{
    if ($collection instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection::class && $filter->getField() === 'email_preference') {
        $values = !is_array($filter->getValue()) ? explode(',', $filter->getValue()) : $filter->getValue();
        foreach ($values as $item) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($filter->getField(), ['finset' => $item]);
        }
    } else {
       $proceed($collection, $filter);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested for an EAV entity like "customer" but it looks like it might work for a flat one. but the filter appliers should be entity type agnostic.

If you want `OR` instead of `AND` for the filter, you need to adjust the way you add the filters but the idea should be the same.

you can also try with a plugin on `addFieldToFilter` on the `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection` class, but this looks trickier

Comment: Thanks Marius , This could actually work, it is a good approach :)